# what are these artefacts/faces and ho do I get rid of them?

Tags: modeling, faces

[image]
[image]
[image]
as shown in the pictures I get these untouchable faces that are part of the bottom face when I move some of the vertex. It does not have any edges, nor does it have any visible vertex. they are glitching in and out when I move the vertex, and seem to increase in size when I pull the wanted vertex in any direction. I have no idea how to remove them, please help!

Answer (score 0):

This screenshots do not clearly show the problem, but it seems that this kind of problem might be particularly tricky to demonstrate visually since it is a visual error.

What I suspect has happened is you’ve managed to end up with bent faces. This can only happen with faces with more than three sides, and when you bend them, you’ll find that the 3-D render engine (whether it be real time OpenGL or cycles) is actually breaking the face up into triangles. This is somewhat arbitrary to the end user, so if the face bends, things get unpredictable.

As is, I can’t really tell what you’re trying to make, or where exactly the problem is, I’m not sure how to fix it. One way to diagnose the problem better would be to select all, and then Split Non-planar Faces (either in the mesh or the face menu, I don’t remember which).